# The fastest way to iterate through file system

Tags: c++, linux, file, filesystems, hard-drive

Sometimes I need to traverse a folder recursively, reading the contents of all files within.

I use C++ and Linux.

The folder contents are arbitrary, from a billion of tiny files to a dozen of gargantuan ones.

Trying to achieve the highest reading speed, I ran into a dilemma.
On one hand, it is almost always faster to perform all reading from one thread, because parallel access to the file system leads to head thrashing between concurrently read files:
[image]

On the other hand, sequential access to the file system from one thread is not as fast as it could be, for two reasons.

First, the time spent between completion of the previous read request and initiation of the next one is lost. I try to minimize it as much as I can by doing literally nothing in the reading thread aside from reading itself, but constant switching between user and kernel space it is still *some* time lost, especially in the aforementioned case of billions of tiny files.
[image]

Second, single-thread reading does not allow the kernel and/or the HDD controller to perform some reordering of the requested sectors, which could improve performance.

So, I would like to achieve two things:

1) In e.g. LibUsb, I can have several pending read requests, which are processed sequentially **but** with no pause between the completion of the previous request and initiation of the next one. Is it possible to get something like that for FS access?

[image]

2) Is it possible to submit several read requests to the kernel at the same time, **but** mark them in some way so that the kernel knows that these requests do not have **individual** deadlines and that it’s the **summary time** of their cumulative execution that should be minimized?

[image]

Comment: Modern drives have NCQ which already does this. Also have you tried mounting with `noatime`?

Comment: @rustyx Thank you for your comment. This problem by definition can not be solved without some cooperation from the kernel, because without it after some time the I/O scheduler will decide that thread #2 was waiting for its portion of data for too long and will switch gears to another file. HDD brain alone, no matter how advanced, isn't enough. As for `noatime`, it only eases the pain of updating the metadata, which is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: @itisravi This is _exactly_ what I was looking for! Please convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: @ScumCoder Moved my comment to an answer.

Comment: (PS: Allegedly, traversing things in inode order can lead to a speedup in some cases (I'd imagine hard disks would have the biggest benefit)  - https://github.com/borgbackup/borg/pull/932#issuecomment-211120899 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Linux, maybe you should give the new [io_uring](https://kernel.dk/io_uring.pdf) interface a try. It claims to be more efficient and performant than the traditional  synchronous (thread-pool+blocking sycalls) or asynchronous `libaio` approaches.

For 1, the `IORING_SETUP_SQPOLL` flag of `io_uring` seems to do what you need as long as you keep pumping in requests.